# Проблемы при рисовании биномиальной функции в R

Tags: r

Рисую график биномиального распределения. Нужно нарисовать для 100000 экспериментов. График должен включать в себя не только линию самого графика, но и гистограмму. Рисую так:

```
library(tidyverse)
summarize.binomial.observations <- function(trials, theta, observations) {
  sample.space <- c(1,0)
  results <- 1:observations %>%
  map_int(function(x)
    as.integer(
      sum(
        sample(sample.space, size = trials, replace = TRUE, prob = c(theta, 1 - theta))
      )
    )
  )
  return(results)
}
summary <- summarize.binomial.observations(80, 0.6, 5000)
resulting.df <- data.frame(flips <- summary) # ggplot only works with data frames
names(resulting.df) <- c("flips")
#binPDF <- data.frame(x<-1:80, y<-dbinom(1:80, size=80, prob = 0.6))
#names(binPDF) <- c("flips", "prob")
ggplot(resulting.df) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(1, 80, 2), aes(x=flips, y=..density..), position="identity",,colour = 'blue', fill = 'white') + 
  geom_density(aes(x=flips, y = ..density..), colour="red")
```

Получаю вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал поменять кол-во испытаний здесь:

```
summary <- summarize.binomial.observations(80, 0.6, 100000)
```

получилось что-то не очень понятное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может я что-то опять не понял с этим R и неправильно рисую гистограмму? Потому-что график получается более-менее нормальным.

### UPDATE

В комментариях задали правильный вопрос, и я приношу свои извинения по поводу того что не сказал где по моему мнению кроется проблема. Мне нужно чтобы столбцов в гистограмме было больше. И я выше это пробовал решить с тем кодом который у меня был. Сейчас нашел другую реализацию:

```
N <- 100000
n <- 100000
p <- .001
x <- rbinom(N,n,p)
hist(x, 
     xlim = c(min(x), max(x)), 
     probability = TRUE, 
     nclass = max(x) - min(x) + 1, 
     col="lightblue",
     border="black",
     main = 'Binomial distribution, n=100000, p=.001')
lines(density(x,bw=1), col = 'red', lwd = 2)
```

и вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не уверен что эта реализация правильная, но она возможно ближе к тому что должно получится. Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы было ооочень много столбцов в гистограмме, не уверен что получится сделать 100к потому-что будет выглядеть наверное не очень.

Comment: а как можно догадаться, что именно «не так» на первой картинке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня ощущение, что Вы не понимаете суть биномиального распределения. В результате работы функции `rbinom()` получаются только целые числа. Поэтому сделать ширину столбца гистограммы меньше чем 1 у Вас не получиться. Используя Ваши параметры можно получить лишь случаи, когда все столбцы заполнены:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(10)
tibble(x = sort(rbinom(1e5,1e5, 0.001))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 90)+
  geom_density(color = "red")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но стоит поменять сид, и в данных появиться пропуск одного из значений:

```
set.seed(42)
tibble(x = sort(rbinom(1e5,1e5, 0.001))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = 90)+
  geom_density(color = "red")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]